# Angular - error TS1146: Declaration expected in Material Stepper

Tags: angular

In my Angular-12 project as I did this declaration in the component:

```
import { MatHorizontalStepper } from '@angular/material/stepper';
@ViewChild('stepper') stepper: MatHorizontalStepper;
```

I got this error:

> error TS1146: Declaration expected.

and it highlights stepper in:

> @ViewChild('stepper') stepper: MatHorizontalStepper;

as shown in the diagram:

[image: stepper]

How do I get this resolved?

Thanks

Comment: You need to declare the `@ViewChild` *inside* a component class.

Comment: `import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';` may solve your issue as it shows declaration error

Answer (score 0):

By just Seeing this error message 'TS1146' declaration expected', we can say some property is used but we have not declared or imported them before use.
Here in your code you have used @ViewChild but it seems you have not imported that. So make sure you first import them.
Import {ViewChild} from '@angular/core' ;

Please let me know if you still face any error we will solve them.